# how to get key value elements in array - ionic 3

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm new to ionic,

I'm trying to display products in cart page which was added in cart. Using rest API, I get a response like this in the console.

```
"items": {
  "29.2.2.0.YTowOnt9": {
    "j2store_orderitem_id": null,
    "order_id": null,
    "orderitem_type": "normal",
    "cart_id": "59",
    "cartitem_id": "29",
    "product_id": "2"
  },
  "30.5.5.0.YTowOnt9": {
    "j2store_orderitem_id": null,
    "order_id": null,
    "orderitem_type": "normal",
    "cart_id": "59",
    "cartitem_id": "30",
    "product_id": "5"
  }
```

Now, whats the problem is **29.2.2.0.YTowOnt9** (cart item unique key) is one product and **30.5.5.0.YTowOnt9** is another product. Now I need to show this in cards and each product attributes should show in that respective cards.

How do get cart_id and product_id in loop?

Comment: if i am correct, you want show return result in card as product wise and show its attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Object.keys(object1) return name of keys as a string array
```

Then you can get product ids with foreach string with

```
object1.items[a].product_id




  const object1 = {
      "items": {
        "29.2.2.0.YTowOnt9": {
          "j2store_orderitem_id": null,
          "order_id": null,
          "orderitem_type": "normal",
          "cart_id": "59",
          "cartitem_id": "29",
          "product_id": "2"
        },
        "30.5.5.0.YTowOnt9": {
          "j2store_orderitem_id": null,
          "order_id": null,
          "orderitem_type": "normal",
          "cart_id": "59",
          "cartitem_id": "30",
          "product_id": "5"
        }
      }
    };

    var arr = Object.keys(object1.items);

    arr.forEach(a => {
      console.log(a) //item id
      console.log(object1.items[a].product_id) //product id
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. i got the solution..but now i need to show this is in html(ionic framework) to display  @Yusuf Kayikci